# Runtime Exception: Cannot locate xaml Resource file

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, c++17, winui-3

working on c++ WinUI3 application

'Cannot locate resource from 'ms-appx:///Sample.xaml'.'.
Actually, by default xaml files are placed under TestWRC folder during build process under CoreApp x64 directory but when xaml cpp code is generated, file is referring root location ('ms-appx:///Sample.xaml'.') instead of ('ms-appx:///SampleWRC/Sample.xaml'.').

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Page
    x:Class="TestWRC.Sample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestWRC"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**Steps to reproduce the bug**

1. create Balnk App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop) C++ with same name
   (CoreApp) for solution and project name. Uncheck the option to put
   the Project in the Solution folder.
2. create Windows Runtime component (WinUI 3) C++ project with TestWRC
   as name, then add Sample.xaml file.
   [image]
3. make navigation from CoreApp to WRC project.
4. Build application and Run
5. click Button which throws 'Cannot locate resource from
   'ms-appx:///Sample.xaml'. ERROR

I felt it has to do with configuration/property settings of xaml file but nothing found on project settings. Am I missing anything small here?

source code sample - https://github.com/GMudide/Bugs/tree/main/WinUI%203/CPP

Comment: You say "create Windows Runtime component (WinUI 3)" but that doesn't exist. AFAIK, there's no supported interop path between UWP and WinUI3, you'll have to port your UWP components to WinUI3.

Comment: @Simon Mourier added image

Comment: Ok, but your repro contains a "Universal Windows" (UWP). What's the relation here? Can you provide a real repro and explains what it's supposed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into multiple Microsoft pages found it as a known issue.

To resolve, add the below target to the end of the Windows Runtime Component's .vcxproj:

```
<Target Name="GetPriIndexName">
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Winmd library targets use the default root namespace of the project for the App package name -->
    <PriIndexName Condition="'$(RootNamespace)' != ''">$(RootNamespace)</PriIndexName>
    <!-- If RootNamespace is empty fall back to TargetName -->
    <PriIndexName Condition="$(PriIndexName) == ''">$(TargetName)</PriIndexName>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

refer: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#:~:text=Known%20issues%20for%20both%20packaged%20and%20unpackaged%20WinUI%20applications%3A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#:%7E:text=Known%20issues%20for%20both%20packaged%20and%20unpackaged%20WinUI%20applications%3A)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have posted the same issue on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8691) and it has been fixed.

Try setting the `AppContainerApplication property` to `false`.

If you set `AppContainerApplication` to `false`, then the Xaml compiler will then add the subdirectory to the path that it looks for the .xaml/.xbf file.

Comment: I strongly believe it is not a fix. It is a Workaround for now because the suggested setting changes the component type to Desktop from Universal Windows which had a downfall.

Comment: I suggest you could directly follow the thread on [the Github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8691) for better help.